# Excel file cannot be accessed when I run python script from Task Scheduler with 'Run whether user logged on or not' option checked

Tags: python, excel, automation, operating-system, pywin32

I am trying to automate excel operations using python. It is crucial for me to use the Pywin32 library since I am refreshing Queries in Excel. I get an error which corresponds to issues with file permissions.

When I try to run my query from the Task Scheduler, with the appropriate actions and triggers set, and the option '`Run whether user is logged on or not`' ,and with highest privileges, I get the following error:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel',
 "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\Users\\kaivalya\\bot\\test.xlsm'.
There are several possible reasons:
• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

When I run the task with the '`Run only when user is logged on`' option, it runs fine. I have tried everything regarding the file and folder level permissions as well, and the folder and file both have Full control permissions for the user Kaivalya, which is the administrator.

I tried the solution at [Using windows10 task scheduler to run python script that uses win32 to run excel file. Whenever user is logged in or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490111/using-windows10-task-scheduler-to-run-python-script-that-uses-win32-to-run-excel) , but it doesnt seem to work either

What can I do to make it run? I have already scheduled the task to run with highest privileges.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/windows10-task-scheduler-cannot-open-excel.897709/  This might answer your question. I would suggest googling your issue, this is quite a common issue it seems

Comment: @mrblue6 I am accessing the excel file in my python script. The link you provided does't seem to cover that. Can you suggest other fixes?